# Oauth 2.0 facebook provider in Chrome package app. Redirect-url issue

Tags: oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth, google-chrome-app

I'm dealing with Oauth 2.0 facebook provider in Chrome package app using chrome.identity namespace and the method launchWebAuthFlow (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow) .

My url of the launchWebAuthFlow method is "https: //www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}"

Reading the docs of this api, the redirect-uri  must to be like this https ://abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef.chromiumapp.org/provider_cb where abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef is the ID of the chrome app. (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity)

When i run this  code, facebook shows me a popup, "configuration of app doesn't allow the given url" instead the facebook login form. Facebook has to be blocking the redirect-uri but i don't know how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, that literally means that on the Facebook API side you didn't set this up properly.

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself.

It's like Xan said, has to be on the configuration of the Facebook app and that is it. The url `https://abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef.chromiumapp.org/provider_cb` has to be written in the 'Site Url' in the Facebook app form configuration.

Comment: it doesn't make a sense isn't it? because the callback url will be changed on every machine?